# I Can't log into windows in VirtualBox without Microsoft account

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox, login

I am opening windows for the first time i get this:
[image: login screen]

I am, using VirtualBox.
I don't have a Microsoft account.
How can i log in?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgaup.jpg) on imgur:

> 1. Boot your PC from Windows install DVD.
> 2. At the Windows Setup screen, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to access Command Prompt.
> 3. Run the following commands, press Enter after each:
>
>    copy d:\windows\system32\sethc.exe d:\
>      copy /y d:\windows\system32\cmd.exe d:\windows\system32\sethc.exe
> 4. Reboot and disconnect the install DVD.
> 5. At the sign-screen screen, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key 5 times to open the Command Prompt.
> 6. Run this command to reset your lost password:
>
>    net user user_name new_password
> 7. Login with your new password. After getting in, copy the sethc.exe from c: back to c:\windows\system32.

If it doesn't work, you can use [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://www.chntpw.com/download/).

Comment: i did not install windows from a DVD, also I can not press SHIFT + F10 because i am using virtualBox on a mac.

Comment: You can download Windows 10 ISO file that is available to public for free download, mount the ISO file to your virtual CD drive. After booting, put your focus by clicking inside your VM, then you can press SHIFT + F10 on your physical keyboard.

Comment: @Alister This method worked for me! Thanks for a tip.